# Get value from Savon XML response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, savon

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and am connecting to a SOAP service with Savon.  I am getting the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <GetInformationsForCoordinatesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetInformationsForCoordinatesResult>ABC14522</GetInformationsForCoordinatesResult>
    </GetInformationsForCoordinatesResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I need to get the value of `GetInformationsForCoordinatesResult`, i.e `ABC14522`.

From the Savon documentation, I know that Savon uses nori and Nokogiri. In my script I  included `require 'nokogiri'`.

```
result = response.xpath("//GetInformationsForCoordinatesResult").first.inner_text
```

However, when I run the code I am getting the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `inner_text' for nil:NilClass
```

Can someone point out what could be wrong here or show a better way to extract the value I need from the response?

Comment: You could use a nokogiri or, there's a Savon to_hash on the response object.  You can traverse it simply (though I don't remember what level it starts at). response[:Envelope][:Body][:Get...Response][:Get...Result]

Comment: You should use Savon's Response object methods. You don't need to roll your own with Nokogiri--Savon's Response object delegates to it automatically. Also, there's no need to require it.

Comment: @MarkThomas - yeah thanks - I just realized I can call response.doc on the response and then I was able to use the code from answer below to get my value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is your document has namespaces. Namespaces are great when they're needed to help differentiate similarly named nodes, but they make searching for the nodes more difficult.

Here are a couple approaches for getting at the data you want:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <GetInformationsForCoordinatesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetInformationsForCoordinatesResult>ABC14522</GetInformationsForCoordinatesResult>
    </GetInformationsForCoordinatesResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
EOT
```

The XML is now parsed into an [XML::Document](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html) object in `doc`. I'm using the [`at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at) method for convenience because it allows using either CSS or XPaths, and is like using [`search(...).first`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search), or [`at_xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath) or [`xpath(...).first`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath).

```
doc.at('//xmlns:GetInformationsForCoordinatesResult', 'xmlns' => "http://tempuri.org/").text # => "ABC14522"
```

By telling Nokogiri exactly which namespace I want, it retrieved the text of the target node.

Or, I can collect all the namespaces inside the XML using [`collect_namespaces`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-collect_namespaces), then pass that as a hash:

```
namespaces = doc.collect_namespaces
doc.at('//xmlns:GetInformationsForCoordinatesResult', namespaces).text # => "ABC14522"
```

Or, if I know there is no special reason to bother with the namespaces, I can tell Nokogiri to ignore them using the [`remove_namespaces!`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-remove_namespaces-21) method:

```
doc.remove_namespaces!
doc.at('//GetInformationsForCoordinatesResult').text # => "ABC14522"
```

Read Nokogiri's tutorial "[Searching an HTML / XML Document](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html)" for more information.

Comment: Thanks TinMan - I used doc.remove_namespaces and the doc.at and this worked.  Is I had multiple Results on the response what would be the best way to retrieve them - so my XML may contain multiple <GetInformationsForCoordinatesResult>ABC14522</GetInformationsForCoordinatesResult>

Comment: If you need to capture multiple results, use `search` or one of its aliases. Use `at` or its aliases if you only want the first matching result. This is covered in [the Nokogiri::XML::Node documentation](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html), so read through it.